# Can we restrict android app keyboard to use other language rather then English?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

How to restrict user to use other language's keyboard rather then English. In my app I don't want other languages input. App should display English keyboard. Whatever default keyboard user is using should change as English keyboard for my app. Can we do like that if yes please suggest me. Thanks in advance.